# Grails - Compare Groovy Date Time if less than 10 minutes

Tags: datetime, grails, time, groovy

I want to compare two dates if the difference between them is less than 10 minutes. How do I do that?

```
Date created = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','2014-06-05 10:19:04')

Date now = new Date()

now.compareTo(created) gives me 1 but I want to compare the minute difference.
```

Comment: If you work with dates a lot I'd like to suggest you to use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or take a look at [groovy.time](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/time/package-summary.html) package if you use Groovy 2.2.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [`java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html). I'm assuming that, Groovy `Date.parse` creates `java.util.Date`, though.

```
def difference = now.time - created.time
if (difference < TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10)) {
    //do something
}
```